# Start new activity or bring up old one according to intent extra

Tags: android

What flag must I set for an intent so if the activity is visible with same extra it does not bring up a new one.

My app is somehow like google play. There are different app that are show in AppActivity by sending the app id as an Extra. User can download app and when download is finished, a complete notification is shown which on press brings up the corresponding activity page.

Currently by pressing notification it start a new activity which is correct for when AppActivity is not visible or showing another app. But it also start a new AppActivity even if the AppActivity is visible for same app.

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(ServiceDownload.this, id,
    new Intent(ServiceDownload.this, AppActivity.class)
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
        .putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_ID, id), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` while starting your activity and define it single top at your manifest file.

If activity is somewhere in the stack, it will be brought to top(`onNewIntent` method will be invoked) and all activities above it, will be destroyed. If it is not in the stack it will be created (`onCreate` method will be invoked)

**Edit:** You have to handle `onNewIntent` to get bundle and update your current activity with new values.

**Note:** Also remember, system may destroy your activity and your both `onCreate` and `onNewIntent` methods can be invoked. Design your activity considering this.

**Edit2:** If you want to have many app details and user can navigate back with pressing back button. And also one detail for one app. Then you should use fragments. Add fragments by tag of your application id/name (something unique) and while showing an app detail search if any detail page exists with `findFragmentByTag` method. If it exists remove it and add it to top of the stack.

Comment: This make things so difficult. Also user can not go back in similar apps.

Comment: If I didn't understand you wrong you need fragments. See my edit 2.

Comment: So it's not possible to differentiate between activity based on their intent and extras?

Comment: If you have some instances of the same activity and you want to bring one of them to top, then it is impossible in standart ways. I haven't seen any documentation for something like that at android docs. But saying impossible to something is always wrong, it can be done with some tricky ways which are probably not suggested.